# Problemas con array Python

Tags: python, array

Mi funcion crearUnArray no me esta devolviendo un valor al momento de ejecutar la suma, adjunto el codigo y el error.

No se si el problema es la funcion crearUnArray, o la manera en que esta implementado con el append.

Si alguno sabe el error o alguna manera de crear un array ingresando datos de teclado se agradece

```
def sumaDeSerie(array):
    resultado = 0
    if array[0] < array[-1]:
        sum(array)
        
    else:
        print('El primer numero del array es mayor que el ultimo')

def crearUnArray(array,respuesta):

    if respuesta == 'si' :
        array.append(int(input('Ingresar numero para agregar al array  ')))
        crearUnArray(array,input('Queres ingresar otro numero?  '))
    elif respuesta == 'no':
        return array
    else:
        print('No entendi el mensaje')
        crearUnArray(array,input('Queres ingresar otro numero?  '))


arrayObtenido = crearUnArray([],input('Quieres ingresar un numero al array?  '))
sumaDeSerie(arrayObtenido)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8632/1527655302.py in <module>
     20 
     21 arrayObtenido = crearUnArray([],input('Quieres ingresar un numero al array?  '))
---> 22 sumaDeSerie(arrayObtenido)
     23 
     24 

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8632/1527655302.py in sumaDeSerie(array)
      1 def sumaDeSerie(array):
      2     resultado = 0
----> 3     if array[0] < array[-1]:
      4         sum(array)
      5 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: agrega `return array` debajo (y fuera) de la ultima condición

Comment: Más allá de la solución al error, te recomiendo siempre que puedas evites usar funciones recursivas (una función que se llama a si misma) si puedes usar bucles.